# How to pass an std::vector<char>* as void* then cast the void* to std::vector<char>* back again?

Tags: c++, esp32, esp-idf

I am using esp-idf to do some http requests, and I want to use c++ because I am more comfortable with it. The esp_http_client works more or less like this:

1. You populate a designated initializer:

```
char[some_length] local_response_buffer;

// I want to use std::vector<char> local_response_buffer for dynamic allocation

esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .host = "httpbin.org",
        .path = "/get",
        .disable_auto_redirect = true,
        .event_handler = http_event_handler,
        .user_data = local_response_buffer, // user_data is void* so the type is erased
    };
```

2. While writing the event handler when data is received you get back the `void* user_data` and copy a temporary buffer of http data chunk into it:

```
esp_err_t http_event_handler(esp_http_client_event_t *evt)
{
    switch (evt->event_id) {
    /* handle other cases... */
    case HTTP_EVENT_ON_DATA:
        // append evt->data (which is actually C-style char* casted to void*) 
        // into evt->user_data (this is our user_data that has been casted to void*).
        // I want to use std::vector::insert here for this purpose.
        break;
}
```

I want to use std::vector instead of char[] for convenient dynamic allocation. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `static_cast()`: *Conversion of any pointer to pointer to void and back to pointer to the original (or more cv-qualified) type preserves its original value.* But I also would use class with `std::vector` as member, not just vector by itself.

Comment: Why vector?  Why not std::string?

Comment: what did you try by now? Are you aware that dynamic allocation can be a source for serious errors on µCs?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy okay that worked. using reinterpret_cast() and using the += operator with the std::string and char*. But I have a question, is += more efficient than doing str1=str1+str2? I mean does it copy the string around many times? If it does, then it might crash for my use case, the task stacks are very small.

Comment: @ChristianB. Yes I am aware of a few examples, I can use std::array if I see any trouble, but the main problem is type casting. For some reason it isn't working for std::vector but does work for std::string.

Comment: What is the lifetime of the `std::vector`?  Just remember that whether you pass a pointer to the `std::vector`, or a pointer to the first byte of its contents, the vector has to stay alive until you're done using it / its content.  As soon as the vector dies it will free the buffer it owns.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes I understand that. I am creating only one vector/string object that is in the same scope as I use it after it has been filled by the event handler, and I am passing the reference to it, not the first element of it. The actual problem turned out to be a non-problem. for some reason intellisense showed me there's an unquilified-id, while there was none and I was wondering why it wouldn't work. The error went away after I actually compiled it.

Comment: @RajatMondal "*For some reason it isn't working for std::vector but does work for std::string*" - then you should have posted the actual code you were having trouble with. The casting should work the exact same way regardless of which container you decide to use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it was an IDE bug, I'm sorry.

Comment: @RajatMondal  std::string::operator+=() and std::string::operator+() are the same in terms of efficiency, _most of the time_, especially if the addition to the original string is sizeable.  If you do not plan to process several hundreds of http requests per second, you shouldn't expect any measurable gains from using +=.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy thank you for telling me that. I didn't know it. I have had problems with str1 = str2 + str3 like operations, the stack overflows because the tiny microcontroller can't copy around many instances of large strings, i had to increase the default pthread stack size. I am using the append method as suggested in the answer instead. Also i might change it to vector<char> because the http response data might contain binary data and to me it will be easier in terms of readability and understanding.

Comment: @RajatMondal  It is usually a good idea to process data as it is being streamed in on small devices.  Running out of memory on an embedded device should never be on the list of possible outcomes.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy the whole project is about an automatic captive portal login system for my uni internet that requires some non-trivial sequence of GET/POST requests and a keep alive browser tab that repeatedly sends a GET request after a timeout period. I know that the response can be at most 10KB. The more taxing job is to regex search some key value pairs in the 10KB data that has to be sent in the POST request which I barely made to work with C style regex (C++ regex required too much stack memory)

Comment: @MichaëlRoy i have some other projects in mind too that's why I'm keeping the options open for more flexibility

Comment: @RajatMondal  My point is exactly that: keeping options open should never not equate to a potentially crash because of memory starvation.  A crashing device is a non-functioning device.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy yes. I agree. I have two options then: either to deal with the response buffer in a separate thread concurrently as it is being populated(maybe using a queue and condition variable), but that would make the code infinitely more complex, or to reject the received data after a certain amount has been transferred (which might work in some cases). At any rate, I cannot attempt to process the data in the event handler, that would be more prone to crashes(from experience). Besides I like the way it is now, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already stated the answer in your question title. You can safely cast a `std::vector*` pointer to a `void*` pointer, and then cast it back to a `std::vector*` pointer.

You can use the `&` operator to get the address of the `vector`, eg:

```
vector<char> local_response_buffer;

esp_http_client_config_t config = {
    ...
    .user_data = &local_response_buffer
};

...

esp_err_t http_event_handler(esp_http_client_event_t *evt)
{
    ...
    vector<char> *buffer = static_cast<vector<char>*>(evt->user_data);
    char *data = static_cast<char*>(evt->data);
    buffer->insert(buffer->end(), data, data + evt->data_len);
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider using `std::string` instead of `std::vector`, eg:

```
string local_response_buffer;

esp_http_client_config_t config = {
    ...
    .user_data = &local_response_buffer
};

...

esp_err_t http_event_handler(esp_http_client_event_t *evt)
{
    ...
    string *buffer = static_cast<string*>(evt->user_data);
    buffer->append(static_cast<char*>(evt->data), evt->data_len);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works now. I had this exact same code a moment ago and my IDE was giving me some unqualified-id error. I think it's a bug in the IDE. But it compiles and works as intended now.